# reload javascript not working IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, reload

ok I have a php website

I need to update "refresh" a page via JavaScript.

it works in Chrome/Firefox etc  but not Internet Explorer.

and it absolutely needs to work in IE. as the software that is using this 
uses IE embedded. :( no changing that.

what is happening...
the page is refreshing in chrome but it goes back to the server and re-runs the php.
which builds the data for the page. this happens in chrome. no problem.
with IE the page refreshes but does not seem to go back to the server.
just reloads the page with the data it already has.

I have tried,..
compatibility mode setting 9,10,11,edge via html.

```
location.reload();
location.reload(true);
window.location.reload();
window.location.reload(true);
```

I have tried to redirect to another page and back errors cant even get that to work at all
Swearing at it
Yelling at it
threatening it with bodily harm.

nothing works.

in ie F5 reloads the page with client side data.
but ctrl+F5 works like it should.

```
$.ajax({
url: "../Core/getSessionValue.php",
type: "get", //send it through get method
data:{name:"videowall_refresh"},
success: function(response) {
if(response==1)
{
location.reload();                  
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try `window.location.href = window.location.href`?

Comment: have you tried using `console.log` within the `if( response==1)` statement and have you tried casting the response as an integer ?

Comment: why do you want to reload the page ? if you are using ajax

Comment: Yes I have. I am using a third party control for a gallery.  It loads via a json source, and it is only loaded once.  I have used the debug and I am hitting that line. It is "refreshing", but seems to be doing it only with local data and not going back to the server and re-running the php page. I am getting the same behavior when I press F5 in the browser. If I hit CTRL+F5 the php is run.